# How to release the private property in iOS 7 using ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am developing a project on iOS 7 using ARC, I want to release a private property when the viewController is released
Here is the TestViewController that is presented as a modal view controller, setting a value to the private property testAVPlayer in viewDidLoad:

```
//TestViewController.m
#import "TestAVPlayer.h"
@interface TestViewController () {
    TestAVPlayer *testAVPlayer;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self setupPlayer];
}

- (void)setupPlayer {
    AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"music" withExtension:@"mp3"]];
    testAVPlayer = [TestAVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];

    [testAVPlayer setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone];
    [testAVPlayer play];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc TestViewController: %@", self);
}
```

TestAVPlayer is a subclass of AVPlayer, I put a NSLog into the dealloc

```
// TestAVPlayer.h
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface TestAVPlayer : AVPlayer

@end

//  TestAVPlayer.m
#import "TestAVPlayer.h"

@implementation TestAVPlayer

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc testAVPlayer: %@", self);
}
@end
```

When TestViewController is dismissed, the testAVPlayer seems never be released, I see the "dealloc TestViewController", but there is no  "dealloc testAVPlayer" in console log

Comment: you dont need to dealloc thats the whole point of ARC...

Comment: @meda yes, but `dealloc` should still get called when released by ARC. Something must be retaining the object, but I'm afraid there is not enough to go on here.

Comment: You might retain it somewhere in block or use repeating timer without invalidation. It's not enough info now.

Comment: Does instruments tell you the object is not being released?

Comment: I edited my question, provide the codes I'm using actually, the testAVPlayer is only placed in setupPlayer, nowhere else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried your code, the problem is that even if you call `[TestAVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item]` the `TestAVPlayer` class doesn't have such method, so it will  call `playerWithPlayerItem:` function from the `AVPlayer` base class, which will return an instance of the `AVPlayer` class instead of the `TestAVPlayer` class. The compiler won't give you any warning because the `playerWithPlayerItem:` method returns a type of `id`. If you check this with the debugger you'll see that the private variable's type is not TestAVPlayer:

[image]

The `dealloc` of the `TestAVPlayer` will never be called as no such object was created.
The `AVPlayer` instance gets deallocated when the `TestViewController` is deallocated. You can check this by using Instruments or simply adding a **Symbolic Breakpoint** to `[AVPlayer dealloc]`.

Select the Breakpoint Navigator and click on the + button and add a Symbolic Breakpoint.

[image]

Write `[AVPLayer dealloc]` to the **Symbol** field and press Enter. When you run the application and the `TestViewController` gets deallocated then you will see that the breakpoint will be hit, hence the `AVPlayer` really gets deallocated.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You are using a class factory method to initialize your object, which means that you do not own the testAVPlayer object and thus are not responsible for releasing it.

See [Class Factory Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassFactoryMethods/ClassFactoryMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH8-SW1) from the Concepts in Objective-C Programming guide for more details.

If you indeed want to own and control the lifetime of this object, use the following initializer:

```
testAVPlayer = [[TestAVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
```

and your dealloc method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

`testAVPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];`

You are using `AVPlayer`, not your `TestAVPlayer`.

Comment: BTW this should be the correct answer. :) I didn't notice that AVPlayer is used instead of subclass.

Comment: I edited my code, replacing AVPlayer with TestAVPlayer, but it still can't be released

Comment: @bandw Did you access `testAVPlayer` somewhere else?

Comment: @Luiz Nowhere else, I only use it inside setupPlayer

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing `- viewDidUnload` then nil the `testAVPlayer`:

```
- (void) viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    testAVPlayer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you are calling it as `[TestAVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item]`, you are really getting back an instance of `AVPlayer`, not `TestAVPlayer`. In fact, the `AVPlayer` instance you created really IS getting deallocated. You won't be able to see your log in dealloc because an instance of that class is never created.

As suggested by another, replace `[TestAVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item]` with `[[TestAVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];` and you should start seeing your logs.